# Assign value to a global variable in c causes error

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

I have the following code:

```
struct TreeNode {
     int val;
     struct TreeNode *left;
     struct TreeNode *right;
};


 #define MAXSIZE 1024

 typedef struct stack{
     struct TreeNode volum[MAXSIZE];
     int top;
 }STACK;

 STACK st;
 st.top = -1;

/* other function definitions such as pop() and push() */
```

But when I compile it, it gives me error `Line 18: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token`. Where Line 18 is `st.top=-1;`

So here I need to initialize the stack, i.e setting the top to -1. I also tried to do it inside the struct: `int top=-1;` But got the same error. I wonder what the correct way of doing it is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
typedef struct stack {
    int top;
    struct TreeNode volum[MAXSIZE];
} STACK;

STACK st = { -1 }; // top has to be the first member of the struct
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `st.top = -1;` in some function (e.g. `main`), because you can't do assigning globally.